# MIT AppInventor: How to handle a large list?

Tags: android, string, algorithm, list, app-inventor

I'm currently working on a MAC Address Lookup Module. I want it to be offline. I have a large amount of text (OUI Database, each item in a new line) and I want to perform a search in it. However, I can't find a way to import it into a variable.
Things that I've tried:

- Handle the whole database as a file and read it (The app hangs on or
  I run out of RAM)
- Set a list variable internally to the
  comma-separated version of the database (The app freezes)

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your _relevant_ blocks...

Comment: you might want to take a look into reading a csv file using the file component...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) might give you some ideas on how to rework your problem. This is a space-efficient data structure and can tell you if something is definitely not part of something and if something *probably* is in it.

Comment: It is worth a try. The wiki page looks promising, and indeed, this is a significant clue on how to rework similar problems with list handling. Thanks!